# Unexpected Number 'var' JS node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Ok so, I am a total noob at node.js,and have a little experience with js,and this could be a simple answer but I've been surfing around,and could not find the solution. Here is my code.

```
var number = []
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on("start", function(){
    currand = random()
    number.push(currand)
    idco = number.length - 1
    io.emit("rcb",{rcbo: currand,idc:idco}
});
```

The function random just returns a random number. When I try to run this , it does not work,and cmd gives me this error Syntax Error: Unexpected Number.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not closing off your io.emit function call with a closing `)`, nor are you closing off the outer anonymous function `function(socket)`, and the `sockets.on` call itself. Also note you really should end each of your statements with a sem-colon

Comment: Ok I fixed that but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Code style is so important. If you don't develop a consistent style you will be faced with these types of bugs all the time.

Comment: Are you sure this is your full script?

Comment: What line does the error say the error is occurring on

Comment: Line 5 which is were I defined the variable. And by the way this is only part of my script,but these are all the places I use this variable.

Comment: Also be careful, it looks (from the snippet we can see) that currand and idco are inadvertent globals.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know what I did wrong the real variable name had a number in it,and that made it not work,thanks for your time.